# Scrolling in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll to a `div + 100px` in the `y` axis.

How do I do that?

`$.scrollTo('div100' + '100px', 2000)` doesn't work.

Comment: Clarify: are you trying to scroll within a div, or scroll the whole page? Do you really want to scroll exactly 100px, or scroll so that a specific div is within view?

Comment: this may help http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin, the [documentation](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) says you can pass some settings as the third argument, one of which can be `offset`. So I guess something like this could work:

```
$.scrollTo('div100', 2000, { offset: { left: 0, top: 100 } });
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but should work

```
var element=$("#div100");

$(...).scrollTo( element.offset().left, element.offset().top + 100);
```